# How to check if a program really works under under Terminal Server/Remote Desktop Services

Tags: terminal-server, remote-desktop-services

I'm some kind of newbie to Terminal Server/Remote Desktop Services and I wanted to know if it's possible to check the proper functioning of a program that has not been certified to work under TS/RDS.
I mean, I think that most of the problems will appear under concurrency (when multiple users using the aplication try to write the same file for example).

There is any standarized/automatized way to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't many programs that are specifically "certified" to run under Terminal Services but there are some that are specifically written to not run under terminal services. Most application vendors don't take the time to consider whether or not their application will be run under terminal services. Unless the installer or the EULA specifically state that the application can't be installed and run on terminal services the only way to find out how it will run is to install it and run it.

Be careful to abide by the EULA and/or licensing terms of the application when installing and running it under terminal services. If the application uses a per user licensing model, then you generally need to purchase a license for each user that will run the program under terminal services. If in doubt, contact the vendor.